# Raspberry Pi idigi http messaging

Tags: python, http, raspberry-pi

I have a python script running that sends data to idigi via http. When I run the script on my mac it works fine and the data is displayed on the server, but when running it from the Raspberry Pi, it can't access the server. They are connected in the same network so I figure it has to do with the Raspberry Pi.
Is access to the http port denied? How do I check and how do I fix? I searched how to make sure the port is open but didn't get very far. Not quite sure what's going on. Any ideas?

I'm not getting any dependency errors. I used the same code that's suggested by idigi. This part of the code that's dealing with the http messaging.

```
    # create HTTP basic authentication string, this consists of 
    # "username:password" base64 encoded 
    auth = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % (username,password))[:-1]

    # Note, this is using Secure HTTP 
    webservice = httplib.HTTPS(idigi)


    # to what URL to send the request with a given HTTP method 
    webservice.putrequest("PUT", "/ws/Messaging/%s" % (filename))


    # add the authorization string into the HTTP header 
    webservice.putheader("Authorization", "Basic %s" % (auth)) 
    webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"") 
    webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(body)) 
    webservice.endheaders()
    webservice.send(body)

    # get the response 
    statuscode, statusmessage, header = webservice.getreply() 
    response_body = webservice.getfile().read()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the issue described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/116020/python-https-requests-urllib2-to-some-sites-fail-on-ubuntu-12-04-without-proxy

I followed some of the information on the post above to create an example script that will PUT to /ws/Messaging using a secure connection by forcing TLS 1.0 on Raspbian (2013-02-09):

```
import base64
import httplib
import socket
import ssl

username = "00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000"
password = "password"
idigi = "my.idigi.com"
filename = "myfile"
body = "contents"

print "Encoding Credentials"
auth = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % (username,password))[:-1]

print "Creating HTTPS instance"
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(idigi)
sock = socket.create_connection((conn.host, conn.port), conn.timeout, conn.source_address) 
conn.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, conn.key_file, conn.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1) 
conn.request("PUT", "/ws/Messaging/%s" % filename, body, {"Authorization": "Basic %s" % (auth), "Content-length": "%d" % len(body)})

response = conn.getresponse()

print "HTTPS response is: %s" % response
```